# Build spinnaker with docker-compose, redirect to localhost

Tags: spinnaker

i build spinnaker using docker-compose follow [here](https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/tree/master/experimental/docker-compose)
but it always redirect to localhost, how can i fix this.
e.g.
http://localhost:8084/auth/redirect?to=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.99.100%3A9000%2F%23%2Finfrastructure

i set the host:0.0.0.0 in spinnaker-local.yml and configured deck apache2 with proxyPreserve=On, it's not working.

where is the configuration about 'redirect'? 
All containers running well but fiat gets error mesages, like this:

WARN 1 --- [ecutionAction-1] c.n.s.fiat.roles.UserRolesSyncer         : [] User permission sync failed. Server status is DOWN. Trying again in 10000 ms. Cause:(Provider: DefaultServiceAccountProvider) retrofit.RetrofitError: unexpected url: front50/serviceAccounts

i'm sure set fiat false, is this matter?

thanks.

Comment: Looks like your gate service is not configured properly (which fiat is tring to connect to) check that and especially the gateUrl variable which tells the other services where it is externally available (it may be set to localhost if that's where you're redirecting to)

Answer (score 2):

The docker-compose link project is not available anymore. That deployment type is not supported anymore.
The easiest way i suggest for people to get started quick is by using Armory Open source [Minnaker](https://github.com/armory/minnaker). It runs on top of a K3S small cluster and contains a functional spinnaker deployment.

Great way to get started.
I tried the debian local deployment and it failed all the time.

Enjoy your CD operations.